# What are all the ways I can gain SP?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

In the Final Fantasy VII Remake, there is a new mechanic to upgrade and improve your weapons. In order to do this, you need to use SP.

So far, the only way I have found to gain SP is to level up your characters; which is about 5 SP per level. My characters are getting into higher levels, so progression in gaining SP this way is starting to become slower (especially for the upgrades that take more than 5 SP).

Aside from leveling up, what are all the ways I can obtain SP to upgrade my weapons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of books you can obtain which give 10 SP. Each type of book applies to each character.

- Cloud: The Art of Swordplay
- Barret: Sharpshooter’s Companion
- Tifa: Way of the Fist
- Aerith: Telluric Scriptures

Some you can buy with Moogle Medals in the Sector 6 Slums, some from side quests and others must be earnt in the Corneo Colluseum.

There are 14 volumes for each character, and volumes after 3 must be earnt in hard mode.

I've been a bit brief to avoid spoilers, but the full reference is here if you need: https://www.rpgsite.net/feature/9637-final-fantasy-vii-remake-manuscript-list-where-to-find-all-skill-books-and-manuscript-volumes-for-weapon-upgrades

Comment: Oh snap. I'm in chapter 9 and I completely missed every single one of these books >.> Is it safe to assume that each book will provide 10 SP for each weapon, just like leveling up?

Comment: Yes, SP is for the character. So it applies to all weapons. When you get a new one it'll have all accumulated points available, which is where the auto setups come into play, to save you some time.